# How do you convert a string column (with 4-digit year values) to a DATE type in Foundry Code Workbooks?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

Is there a way to convert a column with 4-digit year values to a DATE type and have it display as such in Foundry?

Right now, I am working with a column called `year` that contains values like: `1999, 2001, 2010` and its type is a STRING.

When I write code to convert it to a date, it converts the 4 digit year to a 10 digit year, month, and date like so `2010-01-01`.

Here is some code I've tried:

1. `df = df.withColumn('year_mfr', F.trunc(df.year_mfr, 'yyyy'))`
2. `df = df.withColumn('year_mfr', F.to_date(df.year_mfr, 'yyyy'))`

Answer (score 1):

The date type in spark is defined as a 10 digit year month and day so unfortunately it isn't possible to truncate it...

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DateType.html

A workaround for this would be to convert the year to an integer.